# Angularjs split array

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an array that looks like this

```
    $scope.A = [

          [ "1.31069258855609,103.848649478524", "1.31138534529796,103.848923050526" ],
          [ "1.31213221536436,103.848328363879", "1.31288473199114,103.849575392632" ]

        ];
```

I want to make it into something like this

```
        $scope.B = [
           [
             [1.31069258855609,103.848649478524], [1.31138534529796,103.848923050526]
           ],
           [
             [1.31213221536436,103.848328363879], [1.31288473199114,103.849575392632]
           ]
         ];
```

PS: Sorry if this isnt splitting, I am not sure how to address this problem as

Code:

```
    var latlngs = $scope.polyLineCord.map(subarr => subarr.map(str => str.split(',').map(Number)))
    console.log(latlngs)
```

[image]

Comment: Fetched from an api

Comment: I am trying to plot a polyline in my map

Comment: Ohh, sorry it was a typo edited it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`map` each item in the outer array, then `.map` each subarray and `split` by commas, and `map` again by `Number` to transform the strings to numbers:

```js
const input = [
  ["1.31069258855609,103.848649478524", "1.31138534529796,103.848923050526"],
  ["1.31213221536436,103.848328363879", "1.31288473199114,103.849575392632"]
];
console.log(
  input.map(
    subarr => subarr.map(
      str => str.split(',').map(Number)
    )
  )
);
```

Comment: I have no idea how to read this, is it possible to store the result into a variable?

Comment: Just put something like `var somevar =` in place of `console.log(`, the `console.log` in the code above is just to demonstrate that it results in the output you want

Comment: Nice! Exactly how i want it. Thanks again for the help!

Comment: are you still there? I don't know why but I am return with a different result when I use it on my code

Comment: The result I am returned is nested in an array

Comment: Press "Run code snippet", it seems to work given the input you provided and the output you desired in the question...?

Comment: Yeah, yours is what I wanted. But my code is returning me something else. Nvm, I think it's my problem. I'll try and figure it out. Thanks again~

Comment: Remove the `var` - the `var` makes it a *local* variable, sounds like you want to assign to the *persistent* (outer) variable

Answer (score 0):

A function to do the job:

```
function splitMyArray(arr) {
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; ++i) {
        var line = arr[i];
        for (var k = 0; k < line.length; ++k) {
            var parts = line[k].split(',');
            line[k] = [parseFloat(parts[0]), parseFloat(parts[1])];
        }
    }
    return arr;
}
```

Usage example:

```
var myArr = [
    ["1.31,103.84", "1.32,103.85"],
    ["1.39,103.77", "1.40,103.78"]
];

var splitted = splitMyArray(myArr);
console.log(splitted);
```